# Params keyword with tuple with delegate in it. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a function with the `params` keyword like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder Foo(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, params (string key, Action<IConsulConfigurationSource> options)[] sources)
{
    return hostBuilder.
}
```

But on the method call:

```
Host.Foo(("key", bar => 
{
    bar. // `bar` can not determine type of IConsulConfigurationSource
}));
```

The `Action<IConsulConfigurationSource>` variable `bar` can not determine type of IConsulConfigurationSource.

When I've modified method like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder Foo(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, params Action<IConsulConfigurationSource>[] options sources)
{
    return hostBuilder.
}
```

It works perfectly:

```
Host.Foo(bar =>
{
    bar.ReloadOnChange = true;
});
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is that a compile error or are you saying intellisense isn't working?

Comment: IntelliSense isn't working.